# tail dynamically created files in linux

Tags: linux, tail

I am having a list of files under a directory as below,

```
file1
file2
file3
....
....
```

files will get created dynamically by a process.

now when i do `tail -f file* > data.txt`,

**file*** takes only the existing files in the directory.

**for (e.g)**

**existing files:**

```
file1
file2
```

i do : `tail -f file* > data.txt`

when tail in process a new file named ***file3*** got created,

**(here i need to include file3 as well in the tail without restarting the command)**

however i need to stop tail and start it again so that dynamically created files also tailed.

Is there a way to dynamically include files in tail whenever there is a new file created or any workaround for this.

Comment: You could always write the original list of files to a *temp* file, process the files with `tail`, etc., then compare the now existing files with the files in *temp*. If different, then update your *temp* file, and add any newly created files to your output.

Answer (score 2):

I have an anwser that satisfies **most but not all** of your requirements:

You can use

```
tail -f --follow=name --retry file1 file2 file3 > data.txt
```

This will keep opening the files 1,2,3 until they become available. It will keep printing the output even if on of the files disappears and reappears again.

**example usage:**

first create two dummy files:

```
echo a >> file1
echo b >> file2
```

now use tail (in a separate window):

```
tail -f --follow=name --retry file1 file2 file3 > data.txt
```

now append some data and do some other manipulations:

```
echo b >> file2
echo c >> file3
rm file1
echo a >> file1
```

Now this is the final output. Remark that all three files are taken into account, even though they weren't present at a certain moment:

```
==> file1 <==
a

==> file2 <==
b
tail: cannot open ‘file3’ for reading: No such file or directory

==> file2 <==
b
tail: ‘file3’ has become accessible

==> file3 <==
c
tail: ‘file1’ has become inaccessible: No such file or directory

==> file1 <==
a
```

**remark:** this won't work with `file*`, because that is a glob pattern that is expanded before execution. Suppose you do:

```
tail -f file*
```

and only file1 and file2 are present; then `tail` gets as input:

```
tail -f file1 file2
```

The glob expansion cannot know which files would eventually match the pattern. So this is a partial answer: if you know all the possible names of files that will be created; this will do the trick.

Comment: +1 for answer , In my case it goes on to create file<n> until the process ends, so i wont be able to predict the file names.

Comment: I supposed so, that's why I noted that it probably was only a partial answer. The problem is it won't ever work with the glob pattern `file*` because it is expanded upon execution... maybe when scripting something...?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) to inform you of any files created in a directory.  Read the output and start a new `tail -f` as a background process for each new file created.